# PhoneGap removing Permissions

Tags: android, cordova, config, phonegap

I have a PhoneGap app. 
I am trying to remove permissions without breaking the app.

Its a free learn new language app. It has no advertisement or 3rd party tools. It consists of audio files (play audio) and exercise. When an exercise is done, the result is saved in localStorage. So they can track their own progress. I don't have access to this information. There is no REST API communication or need for internet access.

I am not saving any private info from the user or tracking them.
I have already removed a few permissions.

I am struggling to get rid of these and worried they might be necessary.

1) record audio (Do I need this to play audio files?)
 
2) modify or delete the contents of your SD card. Read the content of your SD card 
3) read phone status and identity

This is what I have in the config

```
    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`cordova-plugin-media` requires `record audio` (even if you don't use it in your app) and will install `cordova-plugin-file` that will require to `read, modify or delete contents of the SD card`.

As for the `read phone status and identity`, it's probably the `cordova-plugin-device` that requires it.

I don't know if there's any way to explicitly remove permissions that were automatically added by some plugins.